How can I properly get rid of VS code yellow underline on import pandas command?
What else can I try?
Context:

Mac/Terminal

Pandas is installed, and the script runs, but something doesn't feel right about the yellow line

I am using a VENV. Within this VENV I have installed Pandas.

When I type in terminal which python3, it returns the version under my VENV

Hover over the yellow underline shows: Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource)

When I run the script with python3 s.py, it runs. BUT when I run it with the Play button (Run Python File), it returns this
(venv)x@x-MBP simple_api_etl % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/x/Desktop/python_projects/private_python_projects/simple_a
pi_etl/s.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/x/Desktop/python_projects/private_python_projects/simple_api_etl/s.py", line 1, in 
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'


Solution I tried so far:

Cmd + shft + p to change python interpreter --> Enter interpreter path --> Search for the python3.12 version on the VENV/Bin folder and select that.


When I do this, yellow underline remains AND now my GLOABL python interpreter is the one selected
I don't think this is desired, so I go back to choosing the recommended one which is usr/local/bin/python3, and I'm back in square one




Have you correctly installed pandas in your venv ? the error you get suggest that it isn't the case. Also, consider directly placing your virtual environment in your working directory and tell vscode to use this interpreter (it does not set it as your global interpreter)

I am not sure why you get this yellow line, I can see that you have everything in place but try this:

CMD + shift + p
Click on "+ Create Virtual Environment"
Terminal -> New Terminal or ctrl + shift + `
Then from the terminal run pip install pandas to install Pandas

I am not sure if this is the optimal solution but this is what I normally do and I don't see any yellow lines after.
